# Cronjob is not executing a shellscript

Tags: shell, cron

The cronjob executes this script without a problem and kills the screen:
This is the cronjob for it:

```
47 14 * * * sh /home/server/sidelife/fivem/stop.sh >/dev/null 2>&1


screen -X -S FiveM quit
```

My other script is entered into cron like this:

```
53 14 * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/server/sidelife/fivem/start.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

cd /home/server/sidelife/fivem 
screen -S FiveM /home/server/sidelife/download/run.sh +exec /home/server/sidelife/fivem/server.cfg
```

This isn't starting a screen neither is it doing anything, I do not know where the problem is since the first one works.

Comment: does running your `start.sh` script from the command line work as you need it? If so, then remove the `>/dev/null 2>&1` from crontab entry and replace with `> /tmp/start.log.$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d.\%H:\%M` and look at the contents o that file after it has run. Good luck.

Comment: Is your `sh` actually `/usr/bin/sh`? Not `/bin/sh`?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info or crontab debugging etc tricks. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, the script works from the commandline, i'll test the log file. And the sh is located there, I used whereis sh to find that out

Comment: I tried it using @Shellter ' method, but the problem is, no file is being generated..

Comment: Ok, you have to get just the simplest thing working from the crontab. Eliminate the date stuff at the end for now. So just `53 14 * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/server/sidelife/fivem/start.sh > /tmp/start.sh.log 2>&1` . (Adjusting the time of course). You are checking that your system time matches your wristwatch or other clock? It might help to set it 5, 10 mins in the future, and then go for a short walk. Now do you have a file? If not, then check the email account for the user that owns the crontab account on your local machine. You should get some error messages there. ...

Comment: Pointing you again to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info . Good luck.

Comment: If still no luck, simplify the cron entry further. Something like `3 14 * * *  echo test > /tmp/myTest.log 2>&1` . Oh yeah, and as mentioned above, `/usr/bin/sh` could be causing problems, you shouldn't need that at all. just `3 14 * * *  /home/server/sidelife/fivem/start.sh > /tmp/start.sh.log 2>&1` should work. Jumping back to the beginning, make sure to `chmod +x /home/server/sidelife/fivem/start.sh` and confirm with /bin/ls -l start.sh`. Good luck.